# Datatable ServerSide Processing Custom Loading Screen

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using datatable with the server side rending. By default Datatable show a small processing message, but this message won't be visible if the laoding records are more than 50 in default view. i tried to set and overflow for customer loading screen but its not working.

here is my code.

```
var trd= $('#datableTable').DataTable({

            // Use Ajax to submit form data

            "oLanguage": {
                "sProcessing" : "<div id='overlay'><h2>Loading .. Please wait</h2></div>"
            },
           "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
           'pageLength': 50,
           "sortable": false,
           'lengthMenu': [[10, 20, 25, 50,100, -1], [10, 20, 25, 50,100, 'All']],
           "order": [
               [0, 'desc']
           ],
 dom: 'lBfrtip',

            ajax:({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
              //  data:fmdata,
              //  data: { data: data },
                type: "GET",
                url: '{{ url('admin/reports/get-report') }}'+goURI,

                "dataSrc": function(json) {

                    var return_data = new Array();
                    for(var i=0;i< json.data.length; i++){
                        //console.log(json[i].conversion_id);
                        return_data.push({
                            'id': json.data[i].data_id,

                        })
                    }
                    return return_data;
                }
              // 'beforeSend': function(){
             //      $("#overlay").show();
              // },
              // success: function(data, status) {
              //     $("#overlay").hide();
              // },
               //"initComplete": function(settings, json) {
              //     $('#overlay').hide();
               //    //or $('#loadingSpinner').empty();
              // }

            }),





        });
```

I tried by changing oLangguage to language and sProcessing to processing. But it didn't work.
I am not seeing any overlay or loading effect. Where i am doing wrong?

Comment: In a pure server-side implementation, datatble XHR requests should have a lot of parameters, the ones that handle pagination are `start`, `length`. Your server should handle these and send a proper JSON response with keys such as `iDisplayLength`, `recordsTotal`. If I may suggest, go to a working demo of server-side datatable implementation on their website and check how the XHR requests and responses look in the network monitor of your web browser. Then compare it against how the same looks on your particular code. That may shed some more light.

Answer (score 3):

You can add language for it

example

```
"processing": true,
"language": {
    processing: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span> '
},
"serverSide": true,
```

Comment: why so slow to display after adding this code? It works but it cause more delay.

Comment: I think because server response data slow.